# ejabberd missing timestamps and duplicate records

Tags: ejabberd

I set up an ejabbered server, created 2 users (`admin` and `user1`) and using a browser based xmpp client to communicate between them.

I saw that when I request the mam data, I don't have any timestamps in my messages:

```
flutter: {customText: , from: user1@myejabberedserver.com/converse.js-86119887, senderJid: user1@myejabberedserver.com/converse.js-86119887, time: 0, id: a4228800-d556-4f42-882b-897cca5b3dea, type: Message, body: hi, msgtype: chat, bubbleType: , mediaURL: , isReadSent: 0}
flutter: {customText: , from: admin@myejabberedserver.com/converse.js-33482782, senderJid: admin@myejabberedserver.com/converse.js-33482782, time: 0, id: 8315a148-7c72-4174-b188-cb976126c7ae, type: Message, body: , msgtype: chat, bubbleType: , mediaURL: , isReadSent: 0}
flutter: {customText: , from: admin@myejabberedserver.com/converse.js-33482782, senderJid: admin@myejabberedserver.com/converse.js-33482782, time: 0, id: 4dcec56e-5e55-4e72-8adc-f064f662af26, type: Message, body: hello user, msgtype: chat, bubbleType: , mediaURL: , isReadSent: 0}
```

I also noticed that there are some duplicate records in the database:

```
<message xml:lang='en' to='admin@myejabberdserver.com' from='user1@myejabberdserver.com/converse.js-86119887' type='chat' id='cf64cb88-5e51-451a-8c3e-b394418ee7e7' xmlns='jabber:client'><received xmlns='urn:xmpp:receipts' id='4dcec56e-5e55-4e72-8adc-f064f662af26'/><store xmlns='urn:xmpp:hints'/></message>
<message xml:lang='en' to='admin@myejabberdserver.com' from='user1@myejabberdserver.com/converse.js-86119887' type='chat' id='cf64cb88-5e51-451a-8c3e-b394418ee7e7' xmlns='jabber:client'><received xmlns='urn:xmpp:receipts' id='4dcec56e-5e55-4e72-8adc-f064f662af26'/><store xmlns='urn:xmpp:hints'/></message>
<message xml:lang='en' to='user1@myejabberdserver.com' from='admin@myejabberdserver.com/converse.js-33482782' type='chat' id='8315a148-7c72-4174-b188-cb976126c7ae' xmlns='jabber:client'><received xmlns='urn:xmpp:receipts' id='a4228800-d556-4f42-882b-897cca5b3dea'/><store xmlns='urn:xmpp:hints'/></message>
<message xml:lang='en' to='user1@myejabberdserver.com' from='admin@myejabberdserver.com/converse.js-33482782' type='chat' id='8315a148-7c72-4174-b188-cb976126c7ae' xmlns='jabber:client'><received xmlns='urn:xmpp:receipts' id='a4228800-d556-4f42-882b-897cca5b3dea'/><store xmlns='urn:xmpp:hints'/></message>
```

Answer (score 0):

> when I request the mam data, I don't have any timestamps in my messages:

No idea what method do you use to request the mam data, but obviously it lacks some features.

The message timestamp is stored in the mnesia database (it's stored in erlang format, something like `{1665,488960,790908},`, I've just checked it in my server webadmin page http://localhost:5280/admin/node/ejabberd@localhost/db/archive_msg/1/

It's also stored in the SQL database if you configured so: in the `timestamp` column in the `archive` table.

Additionally, that time is provided when querying the MAM archive as described in the protocol https://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0313.html#query

This is the query my XMPP client sends (I use Tkabber, but surely Gajim, Psi and other well-known clients work correctly too):

```xml
<iq type='set' id='juliet1'>
  <query xmlns='urn:xmpp:mam:2' queryid='f27' />
</iq>
```

This is one of the responses my client receives from ejabberd:

```xml
<message to='admin@localhost/tka1'
    from='admin@localhost'>
  <result id='1665488960790908'
    queryid='f27'
    xmlns='urn:xmpp:mam:2'>
    <forwarded xmlns='urn:xmpp:forward:0'>
      <message xml:lang='es'
    to='admin@localhost/tka1'
    from='admin2@localhost/tka1'
    type='chat'
    id='15:818290'
    xmlns='jabber:client'>
        <archived by='admin@localhost'
    id='1665488960790908'
    xmlns='urn:xmpp:mam:tmp'/>
        <stanza-id by='admin@localhost'
    id='1665488960790908'
    xmlns='urn:xmpp:sid:0'/>
        <active xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/chatstates'/>
        <x xmlns='jabber:x:event'>
          <offline/>
          <delivered/>
          <displayed/>
          <composing/>
        </x>
        <body>hola</body>
      </message>
      <delay from='localhost'
    stamp='2022-10-11T11:49:20.790908Z'
    xmlns='urn:xmpp:delay'/>
    </forwarded>
  </result>
</message>
```